# How can I get all active streamings in agora.io?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have just started using Agora.io and want to implement it to a project of mine.
Following some tutorials I can already start a streaming as host, and other user can join to it as long as the stream is published.

My problem is I would like to show the join button only when the stream is published and not all the time. Also I will have dynamic channels in the future so Iam looking for a way to get the list of all active channels. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Restful API to get all the active channels: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/dashboard_restful_live?platform=All%20Platforms#get-the-project-list-get

When there is at least one user in the channel, the channel is considered as an active channel.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a way to do this through the sdk, without going to the backend?

Comment: Currently there is no way to achieve this on the SDK level.